# Are nested limits [e.g. lim(lim(F(x,y)) as x goes to infinity) as y goes to infinity] meaningful?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Is the following expression meaningful? 
$$\lim_{y\to \infty} (\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x,y))$$

I am working with the more general equation for a specific function $F$
$$\lim_{x_n\to\infty}(\dots(\lim_{x_2\to \infty} (\lim_{x_1\to\infty}F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))\dots)$$

and can show that it equals 1, given any permutation of the order of the $x$'s, e.g. $\lim_{x_1\to\infty}(\dots(\lim_{x_{n-1}\to \infty} (\lim_{x_n\to\infty}F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))\dots)$ also equals 1.

However, for the two variable case note that in general
$$\lim_{y\to \infty} (\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x,y)) \neq \lim_{(x\to\infty, y\to\infty)}F(x,y)$$

since you have to consider every path, and this is true for the $n$ variable case as well.

It is hopeless for me to be able to consider every path for my $n$ variable function and am wondering if having a result for the nested limit expression is meaningful and related to the "true" limit in any way.

Comment: I believe you could make sense of it with Currying by considering the each variable in sequence. I would expect there to be certain reasonable conditions on the function which would make the limiting processes meaningful as well, but it seems doable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into currying.

What sort of conditions did you have in mind?

Comment: What is the n variable function you are playing around with?

Comment: @DavidReed I'd share it, but the function is related to unpublished research, so I can't yet, sorry! I will link the paper here once/if it gets published in the future.

Comment: Ah I see. Well good luck! Smart of you to keep it confidential. My dad has actually had issues with that type of plagiarism before.

Comment: That's unfortunate... Well, I'll learn from that lesson then.

Comment: I ca see geometrically what $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) $and $lim_ {y \rightarrow \infty}f(x,y) $each mean , but I have trouble seeing what$ lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} f(x,y)$ means geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is meaningful, and it is still a "true limit". It is still ok to take a limit

with just one coordinate/variable at a time in $\mathbb{R^n}$ .This is how partial derivatives are defined. It is related in the sense that when the limit over both variables exists, then the iterated limit exists as well and is equal. You are correct in that the reverse is not always true. And even when the iterated limits exist, its not necessarily true that their order can be switched. Here is an example of one where they can be switched:

$$F(x,y) :=  \int_{x}^y\ f(t)dt $$

then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)dt = \lim_{x \to -\infty}\lim_{y \to \infty}F(x,y) = \lim_{y \to \infty}\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x,y)$$

Comment: Thanks! In my particular case, the orders can be permuted arbitrarily. I wonder if that implies anything about the paths?